# How to correct the vertical position of Accents in Opentype math?

Tags: accents, opentype

Please look at the following MWE. The math accents are placed at another vertical position than the text accents. Not really nice.

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

% Correction
%\directlua{local patch_height = function (fontdata)
%fontdata.characters[98]["top_accent"]=fontdata.characters[98]["width"]/2
%local mc = fontdata.MathConstants
%if mc then
%mc.AccentBaseHeight=1.23*mc.AccentBaseHeight
%end
%end
%luatexbase.add_to_callback
%(
%"luaotfload.patch_font",
%patch_height,
%"change_height"
%)}

\setmainfont{lmroman10-regular.otf}[RawFeature={mode=harf}]
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[math-style=literal]

\begin{document}

Ä $\ddot {A}$

ä $\ddot {a}$

\end{document}
```

How can I make the math accents look exactly like the text accents? I tried by changing `AccentBaseHeight` but that only works for capital letters.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why `\ddot` should be treated as the umlaut; the semantic is completely different.

Comment: I think it's just an A with 2 dots in both cases, I don't see a reason that they should look different. Also the differences between `Ä` and `\ddot A` are font-dependent, so I would like to equalize that.

Comment: as @egreg said, they are different: one (the Ä umlaut) is a connection of the letters a and e (at least in the german language, I don't know about umlauts in other languages) while the other (`\ddot A`) denotes e.g. the second derivative of A. So I can somewhat understand why they should look different, as they characterize two different meanings.

Comment: In text, Ä is a single glyph denoting a particular phoneme in some language (or some other variation on the theme); in math or physics `\ddot{A}` would usually be interpreted as the second derivative with respect to time of the variable denoted by A. There's no relation between the two; actually I wouldn't even try to make them look the same.

Comment: OK, but it is still OK when I think the math accents are too high, isn't it?